# Rails Jquery rendering js.erb partial from another js.erb file

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, code-duplication

I have duplicate js.erb code between different model's ajax responses.  I would like to refactor the duplicate js.erb code by passing arguments into a js.erb partial.

How do i render a js.erb partial from a js.erb file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like you would render any other partial with erb.  Let's say your partial is called `_my_partial.js.erb` (note partials always start with `_`), then in your main `.js.erb` file you would do:

```
<%= render 'my_partial' %>
```

If your partial is in another directory, just use:

```
<%= render 'path/to/my_partial' %>
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap tabs for 3 partials, and at the moment the url and the controller action stays the same (all 3 paginated data sets get loaded) regardless what tab is active (what partial is showed), only the instance variables and their partials differ. I'm trying to make infinite scrolling for the partials, so I'd use js.erb response. I'm not sure what I should do (checking active tabs with conditionals and using one js.erb file/ using more url-s and controller actions). What should I do? Can an AJAX call directly called called on partials not the url?